# combine commit history of two files in git

Tags: git

I have this situation in my dev directory with git:

```
/mobile.html
/sub-folder/mobile.html
```

This is the same file with commits in both places. I worked on mobile.html in root first and then moved it to /sub-folder but its commits never followed. I continued to work on it and made new commits.

So now I basically have:

- `/mobile.html`  - commit a, commit b
- `/sub-folder/mobile.html` - commit c, commit d

Is there anyway to join the commit history on these two files?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're seeing here is you being unaware of the fact Git does not track histories of individual files (!).  In Git model, only *content* is tracked, and its distribution across all the files present in a given repository snapshot (what a commit represents) is irrelevant.  Hence renames are not tracked in any specific way, and the `git mv` command is just a convenience helper for `git rm --cached <filename> && mv <filename> <othername> && git add <othername>`.

To compensate for the perceived discontinuity of the change history of a file, Git has special knobs in its history traversal commands which might be used to tell Git how hard it should try to detect what a human would perceive as a file rename.  In particular, look at the `--follow`, `--find-renames` and `--find-copies` command-line options of the `git log` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the files and commited without modifying them, git is able to know that this is a move and not a delete + new files.